# How to change line color of kableExtra::spec_pointrange when knitting PDF

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

`kableExtra` creates a table with some plots, as [its manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf#page=13) demonstrates.
We will have the following table with a pointrange plot with `kableExtra::spec_pointrange()`, running the code at the bottom of this post.

But how can I change colour of ***line***s of the plot (Note, NOT the colour of the centre dots), when knitting a PDF.
It should be awesome if we can freely specify the colour of the error bar and vertical dot line also in PDF, since somehow it seems to be possible to change the line colour interactively when knitting HTML as suggested in [a blog post](https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-10-31-embedding-custom-features-in-gt-tables/).

[image]

```r
coef_table <- data.frame(
  Variables = c("var 1", "var 2", "var 3"),
  Coefficients = c(1.6, 0.2, -2.0),
  Conf.Lower = c(1.3, -0.4, -2.5),
  Conf.Higher = c(1.9, 0.6, -1.4)
)
data.frame(
  Variable = coef_table$Variables,
  Visualization = ""
) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(
    2, 
    image = spec_pointrange(
      x = coef_table$Coefficients,
      xmin = coef_table$Conf.Lower,
      xmax = coef_table$Conf.Higher,
      vline = 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the package [Hao Zhu](https://github.com/haozhu233) [added line_col to spec_pointrange](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/commit/78988919c2dcadb55544e4f1ca72633d3aa55304). So now the `kableExtra` supports the line colour configuration.